# Rails Require `No Such File to Load` Error When Running in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

My rails app works when running locally in `development` mode.  When I try to run it in `production` mode, I get this problem both locally and when I tried to set up an AWS Ubuntu server.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': No such file to load -- ../../config/environment.rb (LoadError)
```

I can't understand exactly what that relative path is relative to.  There is a file at `myrailsapp/config/environment.rb` which states `require_relative 'application'`.  There is a file in the same directory named `application.rb`.

I can't understand what ruby is looking for, or why it cannot find it.

Comment: Are you running `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` command from your rails root directory? did the bundle install run successfully?

Comment: Yes this is being run from the root, e.g. rails create myapp; cd myapp; running bundle install does run successfully.

Comment: try. `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` once.

Comment: Your app is trying to load `../../config/environment.rb` but couldn't find it. It seems to be specific to your production env, so probably set in your /config/environment/production.rb or some other production-specific configurations.

Comment: @kiddorails your command produced the same error `OtheymWifi:req mjb$ pwd
/Users/mjb/iq/req
OtheymWifi:req mjb$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': No such file to load -- ../../config/environment.rb (LoadError)`

Comment: @EJ2015 I may have other problems related to the secret key, but I don't see anything related to file paths in production.rb.  I think I need to get past the file path issues before I can figure out the secret key stuff.

Comment: can you grep `../../config/environment.rb`? It's likely set somewhere and called only in production env.

Comment: @EJ2015 I can find that in only one place.  It's a script, unrelated to the rails app itself.  I wrote it to extract data from an xml file during the dev process, the script is called `xml.rb`.  The `xml.rb` script is not called from anywhere within the rails app, it's just a dev helper.

Comment: @EJ2015 I do think you're on the right track though, surely I have messed up a config file somehow.  Rails is tough because there is config all over the place (albeit largely contained to config/* and db/*).

Comment: What happens if you remove xml.rb? Just to make sure.

Comment: Wow, that totally worked.  Amazing.  I think I partially understand why.  I had this file in `railsroot/app/models` so rails must do some introspection there, but only in production?  And the relative path is good anyway.  Very strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154926/discussion-between-ej2015-and-matthew-james-briggs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is trying to load `../../config/environment.rb` but couldn't find it. It seems to be specific to your production env, so probably set in your /config/environment/production.rb or some other production-specific configurations/files, which are initialized at startup.

Another problem is that `#require` needs an absolute path. For creating absolute path from relative paths, use

`require_relative "../config/environment"`

or something like

`require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)`

Edit: with some more specifics.  The offensive `require '../../config/environment'` was in a side script of the OP's own making, e.g. it was not a model, view, controller or other file created by Rails and was not referenced by the Rails application.  However, it appears the Rails, only in production mode, introspected the rb files in its directories including this custom script and raised the error.  The fixes are twofold.

1. Don't put any custom non-app-specific files in Rails' special folders (such as `myapp/app/model`, instead create your own directory under the app root for such things.
2. use `require_relative` instead of `require` when specifying a relative path.